# OpenX login Error

Tags: java, php, c++, static

I have been using OpenX for a while now.

I just tried to login into my admin and it keeps returning this error. I have cookies enabled and tried different browsers but I keep getting the same errors.

```
        Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::setErrorHandling() should not be called statically in /home/highsch/public_html/adserver/lib/Max.php on line 223

        Strict Standards: Non-static method OA::debug() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/highsch/public_html/adserver/lib/max/ErrorHandler.php on line 134

        Strict Standards: Non-static method Log::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/highsch/public_html/adserver/lib/OA.php on line 149

        Strict Standards: Non-static method Log::factory() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/highsch/public_html/adserver/lib/pear/Log.php on line 199

        Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/highsch/public_html/adserver/lib/OA.php on line 156
```

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to PHP 5.4.x OpenX will show those errors.

You could solve this problem *correctly* by modifying the methods:

```
function setErrorHandling($txt){
```

to

```
public static function setErrorHandling($txt){
```

But that takes a long time, so it might be in your benefit to just change `error_reporting` to disable the Strict Notifications. To do so, simply edit the init.php file in your root directory and change

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

to

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
```

Don’t forget to update the maintenance script. It’s called by a cronjob and the init.php file is not included there.

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method OX_Admin_Timezones::getTimezone() should not be called statically in /www/openx-2.8.10/scripts/maintenance/maintenance.php on line 46
```

Update this file:

```
openx/scripts/maintenance/maintenance.php
```

And add the error_reporting to the top of the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
```

These directions taken from http://www.teslina.com/en/tutorials/openx/fehlermeldungen-problemlosungen/

Comment: @BenjaminDzamesi if this answer solved or help to solve your problem, please select it as the best answer.